# Sub-classed UITableView with background not displaying static cells

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I am trying to make a view controller which deals with the user login. Since I needed the view controller to be scrollable, contain a separate view (for the login), and contain a background, I decided to go with the route of making a tableviewcontroller, subclassing it, and than adding in the necessary views. I subclassed UITableViewController and added this code into the viewdidload()

```
UIImageView *tempImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"TableViewControllerBlurred.png"]];

[tempImageView setFrame:self.tableView.frame];



self.tableView.backgroundView = tempImageView;

[tempImageView release];
```

This successfully added my background image to the controller and at this point, the view controller looked like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/N0TJO.jpg as it was supposed to.

Moving on, I began working with static cells, dropped in a view into one of the cells and began to design the sign in screen. At this point, my storyboard looked like: http://imgur.com/n6GKeGq&ST4H8uf but the problem comes about when I run the project.

When I run the project, I keep getting the same background screen as seen in the first image without any of the new static cells or views. All and any help is much appreciated as to what may be the cause of this problem. Thank you.

CellForRowAtIndexPath Code:

```
*/
(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath     *)indexPath
{
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:<#@"reuseIdentifier"#> forIndexPath:indexPath];

// Configure the cell...

return cell;
}
*/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you want is a UITableView with just static cells, then learn to use UIScrollView with a UIViewController.

```
@interface vc : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIScrollView *scrollView;
@end

@implementation vc
- (id)init // or whatever initializer you are using to make your view controller
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,568)];
        [_scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320,568)];  // equals one screen
        [_scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320,568*2)];  // equals two screens, etc
        // contentSize property determines how much you can scroll inside the UIScrollView view if that makes any sense to you.

        [self.view addSubview:_scrollView]

        // one way of adding a background
        UIImageView *backgroundImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"imageName"]];
        [self.view addSubview:backgroundImageView];

        [_scrollView addSubview:[self newStaticCellAtPosition:CGRectMake(0,0,320,45)]];
        [_scrollView addSubview:[self newStaticCellAtPosition:CGRectMake(0,45,320,45)]];
        // add subviews, you can even use UITableViewCell if you want.
        // I'd use simple UIView's and draw separators and whatnot myself if I were you.
    }

    return self;
}

- (UIView *)newStaticCellAtPosition:(CGRect)position
{
    UIView *staticCell = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:position];
    [staticCell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    return staticCell;
}

@end
```

For other properties you should check out UIScrollView documentation.  Remember UITableView inherits from UIScrollView so if it's easy to pick and choose what you want.

Comment: How would I implement a UIScrollView with a UIViewController?

Comment: here's some code to get you started, basically just create a UIScrollView object property and add it to the controller view, then add subviews to it. good luck!

Comment: Thank you @believesInSanta Just one more question... How would I add a background to that?

Answer (score 0):

first check datasource and delegate of tableview has to be set.
You might be geeting a problem beacuse of that.

Answer (score 0):

Never use a UITableViewController! In almost every case I have come across it is much much easier to use a UIViewController and add a table view. You simply cannot get at the backgroundView of a UITableViewController and have it scroll properly. I realize that you can only make a "static" table view with a UITableViewController but its simple enough to mimic the exact same behaviour with a regular table view and you don't have to deal with the headache of not being able to add views behind the table (like a background image).

Comment: I would happily use a view controller with a table view inside it rather than a tableviewcontroller. The problem is that when I make the view controller, add in the table view with the prototype content, I can't seem to figure out how to change the background of the table view. Any ideas?

Comment: What I would do is use a regular UIViewController, add a table view, then just create cells with different identifiers in storyboard. This mimics static table view behaviour and works exactly the same...The problem with a UITableViewController is that the main view IS the table view, so you essentially cannot add any type of background below it. In my experience all problems such as yours have come form attempting to make a UITableViewController work.