# ScrollView Objective C

Tags: scrollview

I am trying to add a scrollview on my view controller.
First I changed the Simulated size of View Controller to Freeform.
Add new scrollview and change the height to 1000

Added couple of tags.
select all these tags and embedded in a view.
I name this view as contentView.
then,

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    [self.scrollView layoutIfNeeded];
    self.scrollView.contentSize = self.contentView.bounds.size;
}
```

didn't work, for sure i miss something.

Any advise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can check out my answer on this [other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25563309/sub-classed-uitableview-with-background-not-displaying-static-cells/25564024#25564024) and get an idea how to use UIScrollView.